# StreamReader Small vs. Big File Read Times Don't Line Up

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, performance, io, streamreader

See the below code.  This is basically just an experiment on my part so I can get the hang of various things in Visual Basic, i.e. how to use background workers, read files, etc.

I have a small file of 100,000 lines, and a big file of 1,000,000 lines.

The file is structured as "Data A|Data A-1", new line, "Data A|Data A-2", etc., all the way down.

What I'm doing is letting the user select the file, and then populating it to two list boxes just to be able to see that the data is reading correctly.

The below code takes about 22 seconds on my machine to read to completion for the small file, but the big file takes 8 and a half minutes to complete.  For the larger file, I'd expect a time between 3:30 and 4 minutes, based on the line count.  Where is this extra time coming from?  Is there anything I can do to get rid of it?

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class frmMain
Dim WithEvents bwWorkerThread As BackgroundWorker = New BackgroundWorker
Dim strFilePath As String 'record user selected file path

Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    bwWorkerThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True 'this thread can be stopped mid-process
    bwWorkerThread.WorkerReportsProgress = True 'this thread gives updates on how it is doing
End Sub

'When you click "Start"
Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    btnStart.Enabled = False 'disable start button, so user can't start it while it is still in progress
    btnStop.Enabled = True 'enable stop button, so user can stop it only after it has begun

    Dim ofdThreadTest As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
    ofdThreadTest.CheckFileExists = True 'don't process fake files...
    ofdThreadTest.CheckPathExists = True '...or fake pathways
    ofdThreadTest.ReadOnlyChecked = True 'only read, no writing
    ofdThreadTest.ValidateNames = True 'don't process invalid names
    ofdThreadTest.Filter = "Files (*.dat)|*.dat" 'only allow the user to select and open the appropriate files

    If ofdThreadTest.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then 'only run if the user actually selects a file...
        strFilePath = ofdThreadTest.FileName '...store the file name and pathway to a string...
        Me.Text = ofdThreadTest.SafeFileName & " Loading Now..." '...let the user know we're loading...
        bwWorkerThread.RunWorkerAsync() '...then fire the bwWorkerThread DoWork event
    End If

End Sub

'When you click "Stop"
Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    btnStart.Enabled = True 'enable the start button, so the user can restart the process after it has been stopped
    btnStop.Enabled = False 'disable the stop button, so that it can't be stopped when no longer in progress

    If bwWorkerThread.IsBusy Then 'if the thread is active...
        If bwWorkerThread.WorkerSupportsCancellation Then '...and it can be cancelled in-flight...
            bwWorkerThread.CancelAsync() '...kill the thread
        End If
    End If

End Sub

'Background Thread Main Task
Private Sub bwWorkerThread_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwWorkerThread.DoWork


    Dim srFileTest As New IO.StreamReader(strFilePath)
    Dim strDelimter As String = "|"

    Dim intCounter As Integer = 0
    Dim intFileLength As Integer = _
        File.ReadAllLines(strFilePath).Length


    Try
        While srFileTest.Peek() >= 0

            If bwWorkerThread.CancellationPending Then
                e.Cancel = True
                Exit While
                Exit Try
            End If

            Dim strCurrentLine As String = srFileTest.ReadLine()
            Dim strEntry As String() = strCurrentLine.Split(strDelimter.ToCharArray())

            Dim objStore As New ExampleFile()

            objStore.DataPoint = strEntry(0)
            objStore.Process = strEntry(1)

            SetListBox_ThreadSafe(Me.listOne, objStore.DataPoint)
            SetListBox_ThreadSafe(Me.listTwo, objStore.Process)

            intCounter = intCounter + 1

            bwWorkerThread.ReportProgress(CInt((intCounter / intFileLength) * 100))

        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Something unexpected happened!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

    MessageBox.Show(intFileLength.ToString)

End Sub

'Background Thread Progress Updates
Private Sub bwWorkerThread_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bwWorkerThread.ProgressChanged

    Me.progMain.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    Me.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString & "% Finished"

End Sub

'Background Thread Finished
Private Sub bwWorkerThread_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwWorkerThread.RunWorkerCompleted
    If e.Cancelled Then
        Me.Text = "File Test - Operation Cancelled!"
    Else
        Me.Text = "File Test - Finished!"
    End If
End Sub

'Courier between bwWorkerThread and UI thread for list boxes
Delegate Sub SetListBox_Delegate(ByVal [ListBox] As ListBox, ByVal [value] As String)

Private Sub SetListBox_ThreadSafe(ByVal [ListBox] As ListBox, ByVal [value] As String)
    If [ListBox].InvokeRequired Then
        Dim MyListDelegate As New SetListBox_Delegate(AddressOf SetListBox_ThreadSafe)
        Me.Invoke(MyListDelegate, New Object() {[ListBox], [value]})
    Else
        [ListBox].Items.Add([value])
    End If
End Sub
End Class

'structure of example file in use
Public Class ExampleFile
    Public Property DataPoint As String
    Public Property Process As String
End Class
```

Comment: Reading all the lines in memory just to find the number of lines could be memory intensive expecially with 1 million of lines. You could try removing that code and the update progress call to see how the timings change

Comment: The more lines you load into the ListBox, the longer it will take to render.  Try disabling the rendering of the ListBox until all the lines have been loaded.

Comment: Even without a proper database, if the files were CSV, you could use OleDB to parse it and read it in (as typed data) pretty darn quickly.  Then use the result as a DataSource so you arent pushing data into the items collection at all